# Bash: Find files containing a certain string and copy them into a folder

Tags: linux, bash, search, find, copy

What I want:
In a bash script: Find all files in current directory that contain a certain string "teststring" and cop them into a subfolder "./testfolder"

Found this to find the filenames which im looking for

**find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l "teststring"**

..and this to copy found files to another folder (here selecting by strings in filename):

**find . -type f -iname "*stringinfilename*" -exec cp {} ./testfolder/ \;**

Whats the best way to combine both commands to achieve what I described at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let find do both:

```
find . -name subdir -prune -o -type f -exec \
    grep -q teststring "{}" \; -exec cp "{}" subdir \;
```

Note that things like this are much easier if you don't try to add to the directory you're working in.  In other words, write to a sibling dir instead of writing to a subdirectory.  If you want to wind up with the data in a subdir, `mv` it when you're done.  That way, you don't have to worry about the `prune` (ie, you don't have to worry about find descending into the subdir and attempting to duplicate the work).

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, it works. For my understanding how and in what order it works:

Comment: from left to right: 1) find all files in . without descending into subdir. 2) check each of the files if it contains the string with grep 3) copy found files to the subdir.  I guess these steps are somehow executed within the find function. Why do i need the escaped \;?

Comment: The `;` terminates the `-exec` command.  If you omit it, find will complain.